# Harvesting projects with Heat missing KeyPath

Tags: wix, heat

Could someone please educate me as to why, when I harvest a project using 'heat project' command it doesn't set the KeyPath attribute on any of the files?

```
heat project MyApp.csproj -Configuration Release -pog Binaries -pog Content -pog Satellites -ke -directoryid MyAppDir -gg -g1 -out D:\MyApp.wxs
```

In the output, I have 1 file per component so I don't understand why it doesn't set it. I've used 'Heat dir' for some 3rd party libraries that's fine.

I'm sure there's a good reason, but I'm fairly new to WiX and there doesn't seem to be a great deal of info.

Please put me out of my misery.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

> I have 1 file per component so I don't understand why it doesn't set it

When you have a wix Component element with one file, that file automatically becomes the keypath of the component. It is not necessary to specify it explicitly. You can verify this by opening the produced MSI file with [orca](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255905) and examining the `KeyPath` field in the [Component table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368007%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This behavior is described in the documentation of the `KeyPath` attribute for the [Component element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_component.htm).

Comment: I see, that makes sense thanks. But is there a reason for the different behaviour of Heat project and Heat dir with respect to explicitly specifying KeyPath?